# recommended design pattern java dynamic invocation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following db table:

```
id method_id
1   1
1   2
1   3
```

and 2 classes:

`EmailController` `and Smscontroller`

in my code, I need to iterate over the table and according to the method_id (1 or 2) to invoke the send method of either EmailController or Smscontroller.

What is the recommended design pattern for it?

**EDITED**

There could be 100 methods! I put only 3. This is why I do not prefer the if else.

As well, the object that I send to EmailController send method is different than the one that I send to SmsController send method.

In EmailController I need to send User object.
In SmsController I need to send Manager object

Comment: Would an `if` nested in a `for` not suffice? It is best not to over-engineer simple things.

Comment: Is "if/then" a design pattern?  BTW, you listed 3 method ids in your db table.

Comment: Can two `id`s have the same value? All `id`s in that table are `1`. Also can the `method_id` be anything other than `1` or `2`? The last `method_id` in that table is `3`.

Comment: @providence, I agree. The question reminds me of [this XKCD](http://xkcd.com/974/) comic.

Comment: @Paul nice one...i think if/then should suffice. A bit better is to mask that in a function like `send(int msgid)`.

Comment: well, there could be 100 methods! so I don't prefer the if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a design pattern. But for ultimate flexibility you can have a design similar to this:

```
public interface Sendable /* or Sender, SendingManager, etc. */ {
  public int getId();
  public void send();
}

public class EmailController implements Sendable {
}

public class SmsController implements Sendable {
}

public class Sendables {

 private Map<Integer, Sendable> sendables = new HashMap<Integer, Sendable>();

 public void addSendable(Sendable s) {
   this.sendables.put(s.getId(), s);
 }

 public void sendById(Integer id) {
   this.sendables.get(id).send();
 }

}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Sendables sendables = new Sendables();
sendables.add(new EmailController());
sendables.add(new SmsController());
sendables.add(new ChatController());
// etc.


Row row = table.getRow(...); // let's assume this gets a row from your table
sendables.send(row.getId());
```

Another solution could be to have an extra table like this:

```
TABLE: CLASS_NAMES
method_id class_name
1         "com.foo.SmsController"
2         "com.foo.EmailController"
```

And then pass `class_name` to `Class.forName` and let it instantiate the appropriate controller for you to use.

**EDIT:** A reflection-based version of the code as suggested by Luis. Note that for production use you should ensure that the passed parameters are valid (not null, etc.) and also handle exceptions with rigor.

### TABLE: CLASS_NAMES

```
method_id class_name                 param_class_name
1         "com.foo.SmsController"    "com.foo.Manager"
2         "com.foo.EmailController"  "com.foo.User"
```

### SendManager

```
public class SendManager {

    private static final String SEND_METHOD_NAME = "send";

    /* DAO for the CLASS_NAMES tables */
    private ClassNameDAO classNameDao;

    /**
     * Gets the row corresponding to methodId, for example
     * (1, "com.foo.SmsController", "com.foo.Manager") then using reflection
     * instantiates an instance of SmsController and invokes its send method
     * with <code>param</code> passed to it.
     */
    public void send(int methodId, Object param) throws Exception {
        ClassNameRow classNameRow = classNameDao.findByMethodId(methodId);

        String senderParameterClassName = className.senderParameterClassName();
        Class paramClass = Class.forName(senderParameterClassName);

        if (!paramClass.isInstance(param)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("methodId and param are not compatible");
        }

        String senderClassName = classNameRow.getSenderClassName();
        Class senderClass = Class.forName(senderClassName);     

        /* Your sender classes must be JavaBeans and have no-arg constructors */
        Object sender = senderClass.newInstance();

        Class paramClass = Class.forName(senderParameterClassName);

        Method send = senderClass.getMethod(SEND_METHOD_NAME, paramClass);

        send.invoke(sender, param);
    }

}
```

### Sample Usage

```
SendManager sendManager = new SendManager();

Manager m = ...;
sendManager.send(1, m);

User u = ...;
sendManager.send(2, u);
```

Comment: For ultimate flexibility, in the last solution mentioned, you could do dynamic class loading.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
abstract class Controller {
    public static Controller getInstance(int methodId) {
        switch (methodId) {
            case 1:
                return new EmailController();
            case 2:
                return new SmsController();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    public abstract void send();
}

class EmailController extends Controller {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        System.out.println("sending email");
    }
}

class SmsController extends Controller {
    @Override
    public void send() {
        System.out.println("sending sms");
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Controller.getInstance(methodId).send();
```

I'm using the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern and the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy Pattern

http://johnlindquist.com/2010/08/25/patterncraft-strategy-pattern/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern